# NSClassFromString Case Insensitive Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am attempting to instantiate classes from different XML sources. The cases of the class names are inconsistent (camel, upper, lower) across these sources. Does an equivalent to NSClassFromString exist for this? For example, something allowing for:

```
Person *person = [[NSClassFromCaseInsensitiveString("Person") alloc] init];
Person *person = [[NSClassFromCaseInsensitiveString("person") alloc] init];
Person *person = [[NSClassFromCaseInsensitiveString("PERSON") alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably stuck with searching the class list, obtainable from [`objc_getClassList`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_51)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to write my own case insensitive matcher.

Answer (score 6):

make a NSString case insensitive by using any of the capitalization methods in NSString (`-capitalizedString` for instance) then use it as the param for NSClassFromString

Edit: here is code based on your Person example. (Assuming stringFromXML is a NSString that you parsed from your XML code that could contain any form of the word "person"

```
NSString *personString = stringFromXML;
Person *person = NSClassFromString([personString capitalizedString]);
```

Comment: this will only work as long as you don't have camelCased class names

Comment: yes i agree, and if that is the case, your answer is the only viable solution. I didn't see the mention of Camel and assumed from the example it would be simple names :)

Comment: Thanks Jesse. However, I do need to support camel cased class names. Appreciate the answer though!

Answer (score 3):

Please don't do this. You're letting arbitrary (I'm assuming downloaded-over-HTTP) XML instantiate arbitrary classes in your app. This is bad, and it's difficult to know *how* bad because it can instantiate *any class loaded in your app* (including ones in private frameworks).

Consider using something like

```
NSDictionary * classesByLowercaseString = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [Person class], @"person",
  [Blah class[, @"blah",
  nil];
[classesByLowercaseString objectForKey:[xmlClassName lowercaseString]];
```

Also note that XML tag names are supposed to be case-sensitive.

Comment: +1 for security note here. Scope the list of possible model classes explicitly.

Comment: Lest anyone think that the security implications of instantiating classes named by input are academic, [this really did bite the Ruby on Rails folks](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2013/01/10/rails-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-explained/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the NSString capitalization methods, if you are guaranteed that the class name will look like that. A general function as you describe is not available, and likely won't be, for the simple reason that class names are not case insensitive.

```
@interface Person : NSObject  
{ 

} 

@end 

@interface PERSON : NSObject
{

}

@end
```

will work and declare two different class types. Though in all honesty, having classes with identical names except case would just be bad style in the first place.